# Django - Adding multiple children to a model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a `Test` class that will contain an unknown number of `WriteData` and `VerifyData` objects:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    objective = models.ForeignKey(Objective)
    test_at = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH, default="")


class WriteData(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    write_variable = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")
    write_value = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")


class VerifyData(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    verify_variable = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")
    relational_operator = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")
    verify_value = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")
    verify_tolerance = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default="")
```

I get the following error when I try to populate my database:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'verify_variable' into field. Choices are: id, test, test_id, write_value, write_variable`

I suspect this is because `test` has only one relation, which is to `write_data`.  Is the solution to use a many-to-many relationship?  Many-to-many feels wrong, because each of these `write_data/verify_data` are unique and will only go in one `test`.  How do I resolve this?

I took a look at:
[Can a single model object be a parent of multiple child objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899769/can-a-single-model-object-be-a-parent-of-multiple-child-objects), but this is a different situation - I'd like to add relations between these classes, not subclass from them.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/S5uMvHuW) is a pastebin link to the population script.

Comment: Does error occur during migrating or regular insertion?

Comment: `makemigrations` and `migrate` work fine (although the database is empty at the moment) - the error appears when i run a population script.

Comment: Sure, check the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you script you have a method `add_verify_data` (line 148):

```
def add_verify_data(test, v_var, rel_op, v_val, v_tol):
    vd = WriteData.objects.get_or_create(
        test=test,
        verify_variable=v_var,
        relational_operator=rel_op,
        verify_value=v_val,
        verify_tolerance=v_tol,
    )[0]
    vd.save()
    return vd
```

which seems to be creating instance of `WriteData` model with `verify_variable`, `relational_operator`, `verify_value` and `verify_tolerance` but this model doesn't have those fields, only: `write_variable` and `write_value`.